# How to dynamically change primeNG styleClass?

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng

html:`<p-button styleClass="p-button-override"> </p-button>`

css:
 `:host ::ng-deep .p-button-override{ background-color: green; }`

This makes the button green, but trying to change this dynamically with [ngClass] doesn't work:

`<p-button [ngClass]="{'p-button-override' : 2 > 0}">next</p-button>`

How can styleClass be accessed in html with if conditions?

Comment: "trying to change this dynamically with [ngClass] doesn't work." can you show us what you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `styleClass` property directly but with square brackets so you can pass in an expression.

```html
<!-- replace TRUE with your own expression below -->

<p-button [styleClass]="true ? 'p-button-override': '' "> </p-button>
```

```scss
:host ::ng-deep .p-button-override { 
  background-color: green;
}
```